# why does this code break the back button

Tags: javascript, html

I feel there is something fundamental missing here.
This is a node app and the `getData` is an AJAX database call that gets info about a blog post.

I can load the pages just fine, it simply splits the URL string and uses the right-hand side as the `postid`, then the post id is sent via `getData`. That part works but I noticed that if I hit the page twice, and hit back it won't load the old page, it just changes the URL in the address bar, but doesn't actually load the page again.

So if say I put `http://localhost:3000/post/&2` it will load the post with the id of 2. I then put `http://localhost:3000/post/&3` it will load post with the id of 3. Now from there, if I hit back button, I will have the URL in the bar go back to `http://localhost:3000/post/&2` but it will retain the data of `http://localhost:3000/post/&3`

My current idea, is that the back button does not actually treat them as separate URL's for some reason, so it loads the cache it has from `http://localhost:3000/post/&3` because `http://localhost:3000/post/&2` and `http://localhost:3000/post/&3` are the same to it.

```
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css">

</head>

<body onLoad="buildPage()">
  <div id='container'>
    <div id='head'>header icons</div>
    <div id='body'>
      <div id='sidebar'>sidebar
        <div id='sidebarLinks'></div>
        <div id='sidebarAdSpace'></div>
      </div>
      <div id='mainpage'>mainpage</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src='../public/grabdata.js'>
  </script>
  <script>
    function buildPage() {
      var page=3;
      var url= window.location.href.split('&');
      var page=url[1];
      //alert(param);
      getData(page, function(str) {
        str = JSON.parse(str);
        var linkHTML = '';
        var postHTML = '';
        linkHTML += "<ul>";
        for (var i in str) {
          linkHTML += "<li><a href='../post/&" + str[i].id + "'>" + str[i].title + "<i>~" + str[i].published.slice(0, 10) + "</i></a></li>";
        }
        linkHTML += "</ul>";
        postHTML+="<div class='poster'><div class='posterHead'><div class='postTitle'>"+str[0].title+"</div><div class='postSeries'>Part of the "+str[0].series+" series</div></div><div class='postBody'>"+str[0].body+"</div><div class='postAuther'>"+str[0].auther+"</div><div class='postPublished'>"+str[0].published+"</div></div>";
        document.getElementById('sidebarLinks').innerHTML = linkHTML;
        document.getElementById('mainpage').innerHTML = postHTML;
      })
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What happens for url without the `&` symbol?

Comment: I think you should replace '&' symbol to '?'

Comment: Axnyff What happens without & symbol? Redirect to home. Http://localhost:3000/

Comment: Giga Songulashvili is there a fundamental difference there? Is ? a dedicated symbol for url parameters?

Answer (score 0):

well, in case anyone else finds the question useful
i solved my own problem

i misunderstood how the history cache works. it never unloaded the data because it does not recognize a paramater change as a new page.

i solved my issue using pushState and altering the state inside the history itself.
thanks for trying though guys and gals.